# Is it correct to use multilevel models when observations are nested by individual?

Tags: multilevel-analysis

I know only the basics of multilevel modeling. I'm trying to measure the relationship between one paired *set* of questions to another set.

A simple example, one set of questions might be, "How funny do you think 'x' is?" with 10 different items for different comedians. The second set might be, "How much do you like 'x'?" so that the second set is paired with the first by 'x'.

I want to know the question, "Is how funny someone thinks a comedian is associated with how much they like the comedian?" In my mind, it makes sense to treat each *pair* as the unit of analysis and nest them within individuals to account for the fact that how much someone likes one comedian might be related to how much they like any/all comedians.

Is this an appropriate application of multilevel models? It seems like it would artificially inflate the n by 10x, but otherwise makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you built a multilevel model in this scenario, you would build a model that assumes there is non-zero variation among individuals in their baseline odds of liking a comedian whatsoever. I would recommend that you do build a multilevel model so you can account for unmeasured variation in a key individual-level latent trait: that is the sense of humor. So yes, fit a multilevel model in this case.